# Loading Text from a .rtf

Tags: text, load, uitextview, rtf

Hei guys,
I'm trying to load a long text from a .rtf file and I want to show this text in a UITextView.
I store all the .rtf files in a folder called "rtf" into the "Supporting Files" folder.
This is my code.

```
- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem
{
    if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        _detailItem = newDetailItem;

        // Update the view.
        [self configureView];
    }

}

- (void)configureView
{
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.
    if (self.detailItem) 
    {
        self.textView.text = [self setTextForTextView:[self.detailItem description]];
    }

}

-(NSString *)setTextForTextView:(NSString *)description
{
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"rtf/%@.rtf" ,description];
    NSLog(@"%@" ,path);
    NSString *myText = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

    return myText;

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.title = @"Text";
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self configureView];
}
```

But It doesn't show me the text and I don't understand why...
Thanks!

Comment: Are you having an issue in the simulator, on a device, or both? Also, have you tried this with a plain text file to try to isolate the source of the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved in this way:

```
-(NSString *)setTextForTextView:(NSString *)description
{

    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:description ofType:@"txt"];  
    if (filePath) 
    {  
        NSString *myText = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];  

        if (myText) 
        {  
            return myText;
        }  
    }  

}
```

I hope this will help some people in the future! :D